# Uploadify succeeds in IE/Firefox/Safari but fails in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, iis-7.5, uploadify, windows-authentication

I've implemented Uploadify below. The files uploaded will be eventually saved to a database but as of right now I'm just checking that Uploadify can access the service. It succeeds in IE, Firefox, and Safari but fails in Chrome when I or someone else on my domain hits my webserver at http://machine_name.my_domain.com/SiteName/

I have Windows Authentication enabled in IIS Manager and given the testing users permissions.

However, all browsers work fine in IIS Express development.

```
<input id="inputUploadify" type="file" name="inputUploadify" />

$("#inputUploadify").uploadify({
    "buttonImg": "uploadify/customSelect.png",
    "rollover": true,
    "width": 156,
    "height": 40,
    "uploader": "uploadify/uploadify.swf",
    "expressInstall": "uploadify/expressInstall.swf",
    "script": "Services/Uploadify.ashx",
    "cancelImg": "uploadify/cancel.png",
    "scriptData": { "photoGalleryId": "<%=_photoGalleryId %>" },
    "auto": false,
    "multi": true,
    "fileDesc": "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png)",
    "fileExt": "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;",
    "sizeLimit": 1048576, //1 MB limit
    "removeCompleted": false,
    "fileDataName": "fileData",
    "onAllComplete": function (event, data) {
        if (data.errors == 0) {
            alert("Your images have been uploaded.");
        }
        else {
            alert("There was an error uploading images.");
        }
    },
    "onError": function (event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {
        alert("type " + errorObj.type + " " + errorObj.info);
    },
    "onSelect": function (event, ID, fileObj) {
        if (fileObj.size > 1048576) { // 1MB
            alert("file '" + fileObj.name + " is too large.");
            $(this).uploadifyCancel(ID);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

This is the basic handler.

```
public class Uploadify : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["fileData"];
        int photoGalleryId = int.Parse(context.Request["photoGalleryId"]);
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("success");
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddler shows this as the 401 error

> HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
>
> You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication
>   headers.

This is the header from Firefox

[image: Firefox Header]

IE9

[image: IE Header]

and the Chrome header

[image: Chrome Header]

Notice the Chrome header has nothing listed under 'Cookies/Login'

Comment: How does it fail? Are you getting errors? Is the file getting uploaded and failing at the server?

Comment: You might want to provide a bit more info regarding the chrome failure.  For example, are there any script errors?  Does the uploadify stuff actually load? Basically, at what point do you know there is a problem and what code is executing at that time?

Comment: I added that I can see the 401.2 HTTP error in Fiddler with Chrome and I set a breakpoint in the handler which is never reached.

Comment: I added images from Fiddler that show the request headers from each browser. Notice the Chrome header has nothing under the 'Cookies / Login' section.